# The usage of 「見違える」: positive or negative

Tags: translation, sentence

> オフィスで係長が話しています。

> 係長: 皆さん、先月の会議でオフィス環境の改善についてお話しましたが、取り組んでくれていますか。机の上に個人情報を出したままにしないというのは徹底してくれているようですね。以前はメモがたくさん張ってあるパソコンをよく見ましたが、最近はなくなりました。えー、今は使わない昔の書類ですが、ダンボール箱に入ったままになっていますね。年度ごとにファイルにまとめるなどしておいてください。**あっ、ファイルといえば、棚の中のものは、ラベルが付いて整理され、見違えるようになりましたね。**

I was confused about「見違える」. In my opinion, labeling files is a good way to make everything clear. Why does the sentence say that adding labels to files will make them be "wrongly seen"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[見違]{みちが}える, literally "mistake for something" → "be beyond recognition" "quite a difference", is usually used in a positive sense.

> 見違えるように美しくなった
> grew so beautiful that I could hardly recognize
> 見違えるほど健康になった
> became healthy almost beyond recognition
> きれいになっていて、見違えるほどです
> became so beautiful/clean that I can hardly recognize